# Which asciidoc editors support custom extensions?

Tags: editor, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am building a documentation solution where I need to use some custom extensions. For a writer it is often important to see some preview of his work, therefore I am looking for an editor that would support preview generation with these custom extensions. Asciidoc is a very versatile, but it is sometimes difficult to navigate in the ecosystem, because different engines are available, which support different features in different languages.

Which editors support preview with custom extensions?

Comment: AsciidocFX can be hacked to have javascript extensions. Java or Ruby extensions are not supported yet, see https://github.com/asciidocfx/AsciidocFX/issues/532 and https://github.com/asciidocfx/AsciidocFX/issues/298

Comment: Eclipse plugin can be used with external asciidoctor engine, hence any Ruby extensions can be used https://github.com/de-jcup/eclipse-asciidoctor-editor/wiki/Using-installed-asciidoctor

Comment: IntelliJ Idea can use Java or Ruby-based extensions placed .asciidoctor/lib of the project https://intellij-asciidoc-plugin.ahus1.de/docs/users-guide/features/advanced/asciidoctor-extensions.html

Comment: asciidoctor-vscode recently removed the support for external processor https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-vscode/issues/443

Comment: IntelliJ asciidoc plugin can use Ruby extensions only if they do not require any external libraries

Comment: brackets and atom use asciidocjs and do not support ruby or java extensions

Comment: IntelliJ asciidoc(tor) plugin can use extensions, I created one and it uses a lot of libraries. All those JAR files have to be copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asciidoc ecosystem has a lot of engines: Ruby-based, JS-based and Java-based. Different editors use different engines and support different subset of features.

AsciidocFX, asciidoc-vscode, Adobe Brackets and Atom make use of asciidocjs engine.

**AsciidocFX** can be [hacked](https://github.com/asciidocfx/AsciidocFX/issues/532) to include js-based plugins, according to its maintainers.

**Asciidoc-vscode** recently [dropped](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-vscode/issues/443) functionality to use external processor (any of those mentioned), so now there is no official mean to use other extensions.

**Atom and Brackets** do not mention this kind of functionality.

Eclipse and IntelliJ use java-based processor.

**Eclipse** [can use external processor](https://github.com/de-jcup/eclipse-asciidoctor-editor/wiki/Using-installed-asciidoctor) to handle extensions. It is not possible with embedded engine.

**IntelliJIdea** [can](https://intellij-asciidoc-plugin.ahus1.de/docs/users-guide/features/advanced/asciidoctor-extensions.html) use compiled Java extensions or Ruby extensions if they do not require any other libraries. To enable an extension you should only place it into `.asciidoctor/lib` in the root of the project. In case your custom ruby-based extension has any dependencies, they should be placed under gempath, which is `~/.gems/jruby/2.5.0` for me. That can be done with `gem install --install-dir <gempath> <gem>` command.

Conclusions: Asciidoctor has a very versatile and easy to extend engine. Broad ecosystem exists. The downsides are:

- A choice paradox
- Only a few editors can support your homemade customizations, and it is not easy to figure out which do.